# jquery waypoint is not working

Tags: jquery

As per my code written below I think when I scroll to the .onscrollActivate div alert should come. But it is not giving me the alert.

```
<div class="waypoint" style="width:100%;height:300px;"></div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.onscrollActivate').waypoint(function() {
    alert();
  });
});
```

If I try `.click()` instead, it gives me the alert message.so my jquery is fine.

So, where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As you see `waypoint is not a function` error in `console`, you haven't loaded the `waypoint` library on your page.

Include `waypoint` js on the page after `jQuery`.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/2.0.5/waypoints.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @KiranKumarDash Have you included this after `jQuery`? What error are you getting

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).waypoint is not a function
(anonymous function) @ (index):66m.
Callbacks.j @ jquery.js:3148m.
Callbacks.k.fireWith @ jquery.js:3260
m.extend.ready @ jquery.js:3472
J @ jquery.js:3503

Comment: @KiranKumarDash Please create `jsfiddle` demo of the same

Comment: is there a way I can achieve the same just using jquery? without having to load waypoint library

Comment: this direct link worked, however downloaded version was not working

Comment: I am having the same problem, and after adding the CDN, it still tells me in the console that it is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

```
It works fine and not showing an error like " waypoint is not a function error in console".
<script src="js/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>


important:
if you place this script file as above hirarchary  then it works fine. At the same time i f you place it any other than this the other jquery or bootstrap files over write the waypoints.min.js
<script src="js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
```