# Why won't my Jquery fade function work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to Jquery and am trying to implement it into my website. I am trying to fadein (upwards) my first row of pictures when scrolling. But for some reason they will not scroll. Can't seem to find the solution, any help?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags always come first -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-AysaV+vQoT3kOAXZkl02PThvDr8HYKPZhNT5h/CXfBThSRXQ6jW5DO2ekP5ViFdi" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/animate.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:300,400" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Prociono" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">

    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- HEADER -->
        <section id="header">

            <h1 class="name">Jessica Shae</h1>


            <div class="container heading">
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img src="img/7.jpg" class="display">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img src="img/2.jpg" class="display">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img src="img/9.jpg" class="display">
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 text-xs-center">
                            <a href="#gallery"<i class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> 

                </div>
            </div>


        </section>

        <!-- Gallery -->

        <section id="gallery">

            <h2 class="title">The Dark Room</h2>

            <div class="container photo-collection">
                <div class="row js--wp-1">

                    <div class="col-md-4 affect">
                        <img src="img/1.jpg" class="work">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 affect">
                        <img src="img/10.jpg" class="work">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 affect">
                        <img src="img/4.jpg" class="work">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-4 affect">
                        <img src="img/18.jpg" class="work">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 affect">
                        <img src="img/6.jpg" class="work">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 affect">
                        <img src="img/8.jpg" class="work">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-4 affect">
                        <img src="img/12.jpg" class="work">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 affect">
                        <img src="img/11.jpg" class="work">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 affect">
                        <img src="img/14.jpg" class="work">
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>




        </section>




        <section class="contact-me">
            <div class="contact">
                <h3><span class="white">Conta</span><span class="black">ct Me</span></h3>
            </div>


            <form method="post" action="#" class="contact-form">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                        <label for="name">Name</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col span-2-of-3">
                        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your name" required>
                    </div>     
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col span-2-of-3">
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your email" required>
                    </div>     
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                        <label>Drop me a line</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col span-2-of-3">
                        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
                    </div>     
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                        <label>&nbsp;</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col span-2-of-3">
                        <input type="submit" value="Send it!">
                    </div>     
                </div>



                </div>
            </form>
        </section>

    <section class="copywrite">
        <h6>Copywrite &copy; 2016 built by Temple Cerulean Naylor</h6>
    </section>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-3ceskX3iaEnIogmQchP8opvBy3Mi7Ce34nWjpBIwVTHfGYWQS9jwHDVRnpKKHJg7" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.3.7/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-XTs3FgkjiBgo8qjEjBk0tGmf3wPrWtA6coPfQDfFEY8AnYJwjalXCiosYRBIBZX8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-BLiI7JTZm+JWlgKa0M0kGRpJbF2J8q+qreVrKBC47e3K6BW78kGLrCkeRX6I9RoK" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    /*background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);*/
    background: #070606;
}

/* HEADER */

.display {
    height: auto;
    width: 500px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    max-width: 100%;
    border: 4px solid white;
    border-radius: 6%;
}

.heading {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.name {
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 500%;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-align: center;
    color: whitesmoke;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

h1:after {
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #e62222;  /*Great way to give single line color */
    content: " ";
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.fa {
    margin-top: 18px;
}

.fa:link, /*Prevents color change when clicked */
.fa:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #bdc3c7;
}

.fa:hover,
.fa:active {
    color: #ebedee;
}


/* GALLERY */


.work {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    border: 3px solid white;
}

.title {
    font-family: 'Prociono', serif;
    font-size: 350%;
    color: whitesmoke;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top:40px;

}

.affect img {
    opacity: 0.2;
    background-color: #070606;
    transition: opacity .35s, transform .35s;
    transform: scale(1.0);
}

.affect:hover img {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1.15);

}

/* CONTACT */

.contact-me {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, black 50%, white 50%);
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

h3 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.white {
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-size: 240%;
}

.black {
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-size: 240%;
}




.contact-form {
    width: 40%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 8%;
    padding-top: 4%;
    padding-bottom: 4%;
}

input[type=text],
input[type=email],
select,textarea {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 7px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #e62222;
}

textarea {
    height: 100px;
}

input[type=submit] {
    background-color: #e62222;
    border: 1px solid #e62222;
    color: #fff;
    margin-right: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}


input[type=submit]:hover,
input[type=submit]:active {
    background-color: #e94141;
}

/* *:focus {outline: none;} */

/* ------Copywrite----- */

.copywrite {
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.copywrite h6 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 150%;
}



/* -----ANIMATIONS-----*/


.js--wp-1 {
    opacity: 0;
}

.js--wp-1.animated {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // SCROLL ------------------------


    $(function() {
        $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
            if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
                var target = $(this.hash);
                target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
                if (target.length) {
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: target.offset().top
                    }, 1000);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    });


    // GALLERY FADEIN ----------------

    $('.js--wp-1').waypoint(function(direction) {
        $('.js--wp-1').addClass('animated fadeIn');
    }, {
        offset: '50%'
    });


});
```

Comment: No need of loading jQuery twice. [wayPoint is not loaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31199317/jquery-waypoint-is-not-working). Did you check console?

Comment: `$(function() {` is same as `$(document).ready(function() {`, not needed.

Comment: Calm down, please. There's no need to get angry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn1").click(function(){
        $("p").fadeOut()
    });
    $(".btn2").click(function(){
        $("p").fadeIn();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

<button class="btn1">Fade out</button>
<button class="btn2">Fade in</button>

</body>
</html>
```

or

```
$('#message').hide().html("You clicked on a checkbox.").fadeIn('slow');
```

link:-[Why doesn't jquery fadeIn() work with .html()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490563/why-doesnt-jquery-fadein-work-with-html)