# AddClass JQuery/Waypoint Issues

Tags: javascript

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
  $('#element-to-animate').css('opacity', 0);
 
  $('#element-to-animate').waypoint(function() {
      $('#element-to-animate').addClass('slideInLeft');
  }, { offset: '50%' });
 
});
```

```css
.strategic-marketing-header {
    margin-top:12rem;
}
.strategic-marketing-paragraph {
    padding:4rem 2rem 5rem 0;
}

.header-h3 {
    font-size:3.5rem;
    color:#6f7fd5;
    margin-top:5rem;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.paragraph {
    font-size:1.7rem;
}

.centered-image {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    height:80%;
    width:auto;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-what-is-strategic-marketing">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-7 slideInLeft" id="element-to-animate">
                    <h2 class="header-h3 strategic-marketing-header">What Is Strategic Marketing?</h2>
                    <p class="paragraph strategic-marketing-paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg slideInRight">
                    <div class="image-box">
                        <img class="centered-image" src="resources/img/index/strategic-marketing.png" alt="Strategic Marketing Graphs">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>
    </section>
    
    
    
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/2.0.5/waypoints.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

`I have tried getting this .addClass feature on my website to work all day with no break through. Any ideas?

Update:

Thank you so much guys, yes the file was not connecting because of the .css. Now, one more question. I am trying to get this code to fire about 50px before you scroll over the element. For some reason the code above will not fire. Any reason why the offset isnt working? Thanks again for your help! Im new to this!

Comment: Your `.addClass` function works perfectly fine, assuming you have included both jQuery and the relevant Waypoint external library. See [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31199317/jquery-waypoint-is-not-working).

Comment: thanks Obsidian Age. I linked both JQuery and Waypoints to the code and for some reason the js wont trigger when I run the code.

Comment: Hey, it would be much easier for us, if you simply include a function jsfiddle of your code (**including the css!**) - first [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51697920/edit) your question and then click the `<>` button

Comment: Uh, looking at the error you are trying to load `script.css`, I suppose you have the code above in a file called `script.js`, so fix that